# Filling and array from user input and assigning it

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

Still learning here.
My code runs correctly through he first part. However when it ask for the 'productName,productCatagory etc. It just keeps looping and doesn't hold the data and move onto the next method.

```
  private static void GetProductData(Product[] products) //A Method, private static void GetProductData(Product[] products), to fill an array of products.
{
    Console.WriteLine("Category Names Are: Electronics, Books, Apparel, Toys, Others");
    Console.WriteLine("Category Codes Are: e-, b-, a-, t-, o-");

    Console.Write("Enter product ID that's length is 4 first character lower case, second character is - and last two characters are digits. ");
    string productId = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!CheckString(productId))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid product ID. Please enter a valid product ID That's length is 4 first character lower case, second character is - and last two characters are digits. "); // loop to make sure item ID is correct.

        productId = Console.ReadLine();
    }


    while (productId != null)

    {
        Console.Write("Enter product name. ");
        string productName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter product category. ");
        string productCategory = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter product quantity. ");
        int productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter product price. ");
        double productPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    
}
```

Comment: what is the first part? what "next method" are you talking about, you just posted 1 method? regarding your code: your second loop has no way to ever stop. the while condition never changes.

Comment: Enter the number of products. 3 (this code works fine)

Category Names Are: Electronics, Books, Apparel, Toys, Others
Category Codes Are: e-, b-, a-, t-, o-

//from here is just loops
Enter product ID that's length is 4 first character lower case, second character is - and last two characters are digits. e-11
Enter product name. electronis
Enter product category. e-
Enter product quantity. 4
Enter product price. 55

i've added an index code
 products[index] = new Product(productId, productName, productQuantity, productPrice);
            index++;
But now getting a stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop doesn't make much sense.
First, it's condition - `while (productId != null)` - assuming `CheckString(productId)` also validates for null (BTW, not a good choice for a method name, something like `ValidateProductId` would be much better), At this point in the code, you know for a fact that productId is not null.

After that, you read a bunch of data from the user, but you don't really do anything with that data, you just store it in local variables that gets redeclared and reallocated in each iteration.

While we're at at, you should never use code like `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` or `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());`, because you'll get an exception each time the user enters something that can't be converted.
Instead, you should use the relevant `TryParse` methods.

Remember, one of the most basic and important rules of programming is to **never trust user input**.

Having said all that, your method also does too many things, I would suggest breaking it down to smaller methods:

```
private static void GetProductData(Product[] products) 
{
    // assuming products can't be null at this point
    for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++)
    {
        products[i] = GetProduct();
    }
}

private static Product GetProduct() {/* implementation */}

private static string GetProductId() 
{
    Console.Write("Enter product ID that's length is 4 first character lower case, second character is - and last two characters are digits. ");
    do
    {
        if(CheckString(Console.Readline(), out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid product ID. Please enter a valid product ID That's length is 4 first character lower case, second character is - and last two characters are digits. ");
    } while(true);
}
```

and so on.
You might also want to implement `GetInt` and `GetDouble` like this:

```
static int GetInt(string title, string errorMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(title);
    do
    {
        if(int.TryParse(Console.Readline(), out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    } while(true);
}
```

That is assuming, of course, there's more than one int and double you want to read from console.

Comment: In addition, and a bit of self-promoting, I suggest you should check out [ExtendedConsole](https://peled-zohar.github.io/ExtendedConsole/), an open source project I've published on Github back in 2019, you'll find methods such as `ReadInt`  and `Menu` to help with user input, among other things.

Comment: A Method, private static void GetProductData(Product[] products), to fill an array of products. The method must fill the array with products which are constructed from user input information (which must be prompted for). Along with the prompt for a product id, it should display a list of valid product categories and call method CheckString to make sure the inputted product id is a valid format. If not, the user is prompted to re-enter a valid product id.

Comment: I understand this is the assignment, however I don't see anything prohibiting you from also calling other methods from this method - just like you're calling `CheckString` - but even if you do decide to use just one method instead of breaking it down to several methods, my answer still points you in the right direction.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you.